# Invalid procedure call or argument error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I get this error and I really don't know why.

I have the following piece of code:

```
Rand = 2
LRand = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
Do While Rand <> LRand + 1
    If ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = "" Then
        desch = InStr(ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value, "(")
        inch = InStr(ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value, ")")
        ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = Mid(ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value, desch + 1, inch - desch - 1) 'here is the error
    End If
Rand = Rand + 1
Loop
```

Do you guys have any idea why I get the invalid procedure call or argument? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you show us how the value would be in the cells(rand,5) like these (somename) huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible

```
 if desch = 0
      or 
 if inch = 0

 desch = instr('this may return zero')
 inch  = instr('when it doesnt find the substring')

 so putting them in mid functions results like these

 mid(string,0,0) results error  
 mid(string(0,2) results error
 mid(string(2,0) results error
```

So check those values at first

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes that the contents of the cell being processed, ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value, are on the form "(some text here)".  If that assumption is wrong, the above error will occur.  This will happen if the cell is empty, either ( or ) is missing or if ) comes before (.

Comment: Oh... so I'll have to see if it contains a "(" before I load the desch and inch variables.